# How do you add images to Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

I've created this page on wikipedia but I can't figure out how to link or upload an image in the Infobox.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimi_Knoop

I've tried adding the image url but it doesn't work.

```
{Infobox Person
|name          = Mimi Knoop
|image         = http://discussion.socalskateparks.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/pp08girlsawards.jpg
|image_size    = 175
|caption       = Mimi Knoop
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an infobox such as the one in that article, you can refer to a image file like this: `Image:Filename.jpg`, but you have to first upload the image to either [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUpload) itself or [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aUpload). (Those are direct links to upload pages).

Commons is recommended (because then the image can be easily used in Wikipedias in other languages, and in other Wikimedia projects like Wiktionary), but the image needs to be [freely licensed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_content). As for English Wikipedia you are also allowed to upload non-free images under certain conditions (e.g. "fair use" rules). (Note that you are *not* allowed to just upload any random images off the internet, you need to either own the copyright or know that you have the right to use the image.)

Outside of an infobox, you'd typically refer to an image file like this:

```
[[Image:Example.jpg|right|thumb|Caption]]
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other pages I've checked with images have a simple image file name with no path or URL.

You need to upload the image to Wikipedia first.